# Tail bounds for sum of weighted Poisson random variables

Tags: bounds

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be $n$ independent Poisson random variables with $\mu(X_i) = \lambda_i$. I am interested in upper tail bounds for the random variable $Z = \sum_{i} a_i X_i$ where $a_i \in [0,1]$ for $1\le i \le n$. For instance if each $a_i =  1$ then $Z$ is simply a Poisson rv with mean $\sum_i \lambda_i$ and one would get tail inequalities such as the one I found in a note [here](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Eccanonne/files/misc/2017-poissonconcentration.pdf). For the general weighted case Chernoff style tail bounds should apply but I am not finding an easy reference. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One can replace $X_i$ by a sum of many binomial random variables and then apply Chernoff  bounds to that sum so tail bounds should apply but I am trying to avoid formalizing all the messy details and cite some source.

Comment: Your link states that Poisson's are sub-exponential. Sub-exponential random variables are closed under taking independent sums, and have tail inequalities. If you compute the precise sub-exponential parameter of the Poisson, then the results from [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mjwain/stat210b/Chap2_TailBounds_Jan22_2015.pdf) should make the rest quite simple.